# how to add an element in the outer body tag and exclude iframe body tags

Tags: javascript, dom, tampermonkey

I try to add an button via Tampermonkey to websites.
That button should only appear in the outer body and not in iframes.

So, for example, this is before the Tampermokey runs...

```html
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    ...
    ...
    <iframe src="https://xyz.abc", id="myID">
      <html>
        <head>...</head>
        <body>
          ...
          ...
        </body>
      </html>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html
```

I try to add an button like this:

```js
var zNode = document.createElement('div');
            zNode.innerHTML = '<button id="myButton" type="button">' +
                'submit</button>';
            zNode.setAttribute('id', 'myContainer');
var first = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            first.appendChild(zNode);
            
// add an event handler, etc...
```

But this piece of code is not ignoring the body tag in the iframe and my button appears in both body tags.

```html
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContainer"><button id="myButton" 
      type="button">Clear Session</button></div>
    ...
    <iframe src="https://xyz.abc", id="myID">
      <html>
        <head>...</head>
        <body>
          <div id="myContainer"><button id="myButton" 
            type="button">Clear Session</button></div>
          ...
        </body>
      </html>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html
```

What I would like to archive is to add the button only in the outer body (not as part of the iFrame).
Please notice, I cannot modify the webpage, I can only try to adapt my code by Tampermonkey...
Are you able to support me here please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**

If the pages are dynamically generated, varies in content, and/or what and how things are loaded cannot be controlled, etc., try adding the button with [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method. Also adding elements to `body` isn't the best choice of locations because it's at the top of the hierarchy of HTML and there should be only few elements there.

```js
const win = document.querySelector('iframe');

win.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `<div class="box">
  <button class='clr'>
    Clear Session
  </button>
</div>`);
```

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<html><head></head><body>There's no button in this iFrame.</body></html>" width='200' height='100' frameborder='2'></iframe>
```

**Update 1**

1. **Use `.class` instead of `#id`.**

- A fundamental rule concerning HTML is that of the attribute `#id`. `#id`s must be unique on the page, meaning it is invalid HTML if there are more than one element assigned as `#myContainer` for example. Under normal circumstances should there be more than one `#id`, methods such as `.querySelector()` or `.getElementById()` will find the first element and ignore any other duplicates because it's assumed that there is only one `#myContainer`.

2. **iFrame HTML is invalid**

- In the OP code there's a unusual layout where there is two `#myContainer`s and they are in separate documents which inadvertantly makes them both behave as valid. ***But*** the OP code is invalid because iFrames syntax is very wrong:

  - OP Invalid HTML (iFrame is an just an inline element)

    ```
    <iframe><html><body>...</body></html></iframe>
    ```
  - Valid HTML (iFrame `src` attribute is a url of the page)

    ```
    <iframe src='https://sub.dom.com/path/to/page.html'></iframe>
    ```
  - Valid HTML (iFrame source is `htmlString` of `srcdoc` attribute)

    ```
    <iframe srcdoc='<html><body>...</body></html>'></iframe>
    ```
- If the iFrame was valid, then everything within the iFrame couldn't be affected unless:

  - The content exists on the same host
  - Use of the [`.contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) property
- Op code has an invalid iFrame which is just an inline element with no special features.

3. **Use `.querySelector()`**

- The method `.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` actually collects all `body` elements and the bracket notation with the value of zero: `[0]` indicates the first `body` in the document, thus both `body`s are affected.

Check the HTML with <kbd>F12</kbd> and make sure that `zNode` (assuming `zNode` is an element) is appended to the iframe. From what little code posted, it looks as if you couldn't have added anything to an iframe because there is an extra property needed:

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument;
```

In the example below the following is used to reference the body of parent document:

```
document.body
```

```js
const mark = document.createElement('mark');
mark.textContent = 'This is in body of parent document';
document.body.appendChild(mark);
```

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>Inside iFrame</body></html>" style='display: block; width: 50vw; height: 25vh; border: 3px inset grey; margin: 10px auto'></iframe>
```

Comment: okay, so my issue is, this tampermonkey script is for various webpages I am not responsible for. 
When I am adding the button (zNode) the button will be added to the main window (outer body) as well as the body from the iFrame. 
But I want to add this button only to the main/outer body and exclude / ignore the iFrame.

Comment: I have tried to add more context to my question!

Comment: @Frank updated answer. If Tampermonkey requires the use of invalid HTML, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: you are right. I can use class instead of ID. 
The thing is, this Tampermonkey needs to run on several customer webpages showcasing a usecase.
So I do not know, which structure the web page has outside of the iFrame. 
I know how the iframe looks like (but I can't modify the code within the iFrame as well. 
I see, the .contentDocument might help to address the iFrame, but what I would like to archive is to add a button with DOM modification to the surrounding web page but not in the iFrame. 
I am not sure if I got your suggestions above correctly to help me to archive that.

Comment: In your case you do not want to use ` .contentDocument`. You might be confused about what is inside the iFrame and what's not. I think things will be clearer if you post exactly where the second button is added, the iFrame, and surrounding HTML.

Comment: Hi, you are right, it would be easier, but as mentioned, that Tampermonkey needs to run on several websites, and they can differ in structure. 
I wonder, when I know the ID of the iFrame, can I remove the button from this iFrame, when I am not able to control where to add a button, when I do not know, how the structure of such a web page looks like?

Comment: @Frank see **Update 2**